# EBS Volume Being Read as Root Device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

One of my instances was preventing me from logging so I stopped it, detached its volume, spun up a new instance, and attached the old volume. The problem is, the old volume is being treated as the root device. Because of this, I still cannot log in to the new instance (although I can do so if I don't attach the old volume).

Is there any way to fix this issue using the AWS Management Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I had to make a snapshot of the old volume first. I then created a new AMI using that snapshot. I included the old volume as an extra storage so that it's explicitly defined not to be treated as a root device.

I then created a new instance using that AMI. I was able to finally log in to the new instance. From there, I just mounted the volume.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have attached your old volume in "/dev/sda1". Deattach your old volume and attach it to "/dev/sdf".

Comment: No. It's attached as /dev/sdf. For some reason, the new volume is being bypassed and the old one is being used even though the mapping is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the filesystems on each volume having the same label (the value returned by e.g. `e2label /dev/xvda1`).  The server correctly starts booting from the first volume, and then the bootloader, there, sees the second volume having the label it anticipates for the root volume, and continues booting with the second volume as root.  This an os-level setting, not visible to the AWS infrastructure.

Workaround: don't attach the second volume until after the instance has booted.  EBS volumes can be attached to an instance at any time -- they don't have to be present when the instance is started.   After unmount, they can also be detached at any time, with the instance still running.

Comment: I tried to do that before but I get an error that the volume cannot be attached because the instance is not in a stopped state.

Comment: Does the error mention anything about "marketplace?" ...Or any other explanation?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it.

`Error attaching volume: Cannot attach volume 'xxxxxxxx' with Marketplace codes as the instance 'xxxxx' is not in the 'stopped' state.`

Comment: Ah, so, that's to prevent you from (either accidentally or deliberately) avoiding paying any license fee for running the software on that volume, but the restriction probably applies even if the license fee is $0.  Your easiest workaround may be to fire up a test instance with a different OS -- if this is Ubuntu, launching one with CentOS or Amazon Linux will probably result in a different root volume label, so mounting the volume with the instance stopped should result in a normal boot-up to the correct root volume.  Otherwise, it'll be a  bit more complicated. Not impossible, just messier.

Comment: That's actually one of the first things I tried. An Amazon Linux instance produces the same error. CentOS as well. I tried RedHat as well although the error was different.